# MS graph APi for calling /communications/callRecords problems

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

i make a azure for my self and trying to call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords  this request

first there goes to unknow error

after that i open all api permision

but it goes to **request too long error **

here is my code (i can not give you client_id and other things sorry )

```
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication
import requests
import json

# Replace these values with your actual application and authentication details
client_id = ' '
client_secret = ' '
tenant_id = ' '
authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenant_id
scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

# Set up MSAL ConfidentialClientApplication
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_secret,
)

# Acquire a token
token_response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)

# Set up the GraphServiceClient with the acquired token
access_token = token_response["access_token"]
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

# Define the batch request payload
 
single_request = {
    "id": "1",
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/communications/callRecords",
    # 考虑删除每个请求的不必要头部
}

# 拆分单个请求为20个子请求
batch_size = 20
requests_to_process = [single_request.copy() for _ in range(batch_size)]

batches = [requests_to_process[i:i + 1] for i in range(0, len(requests_to_process))]

for batch_number, batch in enumerate(batches, start=1):
    batch_payload = {"requests": batch}

    # 进行批量请求
    batch_response = requests.post(
        url="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch",
        headers=headers,
        json=batch_payload,
    )

    # 检查批量响应
    if batch_response.status_code != 200:
        print(f"Error in batch {batch_number}, status code: {batch_response.status_code}")
        print(batch_response.json())
    else:
        print(f"Batch {batch_number} response:")
        print(json.dumps(batch_response.json(), indent=4))
```

Comment: For the unknown error, it is difficult to deduce what could be causing it unless you share more details about this error. As for the second error, is it a request too long error or request URI too long? Just to double- check, the API permission is CallRecords.Read.All, is this what has been given to the application?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BH1c_RgVxjIB1sbkWECAfYegroj7qL_M2BqQedgonjw/edit    i open the CallRecords.Read.All   first error is that i did not open enough  api permission, second error is that i open alots of permission and it goes to 
 request too long error or request URI too long  ; i  do not know why...

Comment: Try the same call on Graph Explorer and see if you get the result sent back.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
Graph Explorer- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Answer (score 0):

If you review the public documentation, the list operation for callRecords (`/beta/communications/callRecords`) is only available in [beta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http), but the link you shared in your code is using v1.0.

In v1.0, the only available operation is to get [one single call record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).